# How does M2 know what to inject based on our _construct?

Tags: magento2, dependency-injection

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category $categoryHelper,
    ....
```

Let's say we have code like that. How does Magento know to inject category helper and lets us use it? It works like total magic.

Answer (score 0):

The new object is created in `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:93`

```
protected function createObject($type, $args)
{
    return new $type(...array_values($args));
}
```

You can see how these arguments are created and cached in `lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php:88`

### How are the constructor arguments read?

During the bootstrap initialization  `/var/di/{area}.ser` files are loaded. These are previously created by the `setup:di:compile` command and they are basically serialized strings that contain argument relations.

I hope it answers your question to some extent :)